# print inorder traversal of connected leaf nodes

Tags: data-structures

---

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jM4Yt.png)

In the binary tree leaf’s left and right node will not be null. one leaf’s right node will be connected to node which is next leaf in the in order traversal. and the leaf’s left node will be connected to previous leaf according to in order. First leaf’s left will be the last leaf in the in order traversal and last leaf’s right node is connected to first leaf in the in order traversal.

You need to print in order traversal.

I tried by finding the node which is pointed by two nodes, and that will be the leaf node.

Comment: And what is the question? What have you tried already? Please read [ask], then [edit] your question to include your code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the question is quite unclear. Rest, the answer I have written is on the basis of some assumptions, majorly thinking that you want a way to solve the problem.

What I suggest is do an in-order traversal of the tree and using a simple array like DS, say vector, store all the references to the leaf nodes of the tree that come to you while the traversal. Now for all the nodes in the vector construct a circular double linked list. Done!

PS: You can directly start constructing the doubly linked list taking every encounter with a leaf node (during in-inorder traversal) as the insertion of the new node to the list.

Comment: Please see the attached image , it may clear your doubt, if still it doesnt , let me know the exact doubt you have

Answer (score 0):

If we compare the given problem with simple Inorder traversal the problem which we face is how to find which is our leaf node to return from that node.

Here every leaf node has a special property of loop.

`if(node->left != NULL && node->left->right == node)` this condition is true then our node is leaf node.

```
void printInorder(struct Node *node) {

    if(node == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    if(node->left != NULL && node->left->right == node) {
        cout << node->data << " ";
        return;
    }

    printInorder(node->left);

    cout << node->data << " ";

    printInorder(node->right);
}
```

Time complexity: O(n)

Space Complexity: O(1)

Comment: Thanks Varun. But i think node->left->right == node will be the sufficient condition. node->left->right == node is true if node->left != NULL. if i am correct

Comment: @RanvijayPratapSingh I think if node->left is NULL then node->left->right will throw NullPointerException. Correct me if I'm wrong